# How does batching interact with the loss function in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm training a multi-objective neural net in TensorFlow with my own loss function and can't find documentation regarding how batching interacts with that functionality.

For example, I have snippet of my loss function below, which takes the tensor/list of predictions and makes sure that their absolute value sums to no more than one:

```
def fitness(predictions,actual):

    absTensor = tf.abs(predictions)
    sumTensor = tf.reduce_sum(absTensor)
    oneTensor = tf.constant(1.0)

    isGTOne = tf.greater(sumTensor,oneTensor)

    def norm(): return predictions/sumTensor
    def unchanged(): return predictions

    predictions = tf.cond(isGTOne,norm,unchanged)

    etc...
```

But when I'm passing in a batch of estimates I feel like this loss function is normalising the whole set of inputs to sum to 1 at this point, rather than each individual set summing to 1. I.e.
[[.8,.8],[.8,.8]] -> [[.25,.25],[.25,25]]
rather than the desired
[[.8,.8],[.8,.8]] -> [[.5,.5],[.5,.5]]

Can anybody clarify or put to rest my suspicions? If this is how my function is currently working, how do I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify a reduction axis for reduction ops, otherwise all axes will be reduces. Traditionally this is the first dimension of your tensor. So, line 2 should look like this:

```
sumTensor = tf.reduce_sum(absTensor, 0)
```

After you make that change you will run into another problem. `sumTensor` will no longer be a scalar and will thus no longer make sense as a condition for tf.cond (i.e. what does it mean to branch per entry of a batch?). What you really want is [tf.select](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#select) since you don't really want to branch logic per batch entry. Like this:

```
isGTOne = tf.greater(sumTensor,oneTensor)

norm = predictions/sumTensor

predictions = tf.select(isGTOne,norm,predictions)
```

But, looking at this now, I wouldn't even bother conditionally normalizing the entries. Since you are operating at the granularity of a batch now, I don't think you can gain performance from normalizing an entry of a batch one at a time. Especially, since dividing is not really an expensive side effect. Might as well just do:

```
def fitness(predictions,actual):

  absTensor = tf.abs(predictions)
  sumTensor = tf.reduce_sum(absTensor, 0)

  predictions = predictions/sumTensor

  etc...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. Is there somewhere in the docs that talks about this behaviour? I'd like to read through if there is to ensure nothing else unexpected comes up

Comment: What behavior in particular were you looking for docs about? The [tf.select docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#select) is useful.